# Tweepy: Is it possible to get a list of members who have in a certain string in the screenname or in the description?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

Every method i see at tweepy requires a specific username or user id. is it possible to search twitter for strings in the username or in the description? For example: find all members who have the string "pet lover" in the username or in the description.

Comment: The Twitter API supports this via the [`users/search` endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search.html) but I am uncertain whether Tweepy exposes this as a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
 api = tweepy.API(auth)

 user_in_twitter = api.search_users("query")
```